# How to unset a variable set with declare in bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following:

```shell
foo=hello
declare -n bar=foo
echo $bar
# hello
```

Cool.

Now I want to undeclare `bar`.

```shell
unset bar
declare -p bar
# declare -n v="foo"
declare -p foo
# bash: declare: foo: not found
```

How do I unset a variable created with `declare -n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, Stack Exchange did an excellent job rubber-ducking, and I found the solution.

```shell
foo=hello
declare -n v=foo

unset -n v # <-- here's the magic

declare -p v
# bash: declare: v: not found
declare -p foo
# declare -- foo="hello"
```